# Facing issues with implementing polynomial regression: AttributeError: 'PolynomialFeatures' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Following is the code I am trying to implement. I am trying to generate a polynomial equation to predict next values in the `y` array

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# creating a dataset with curvilinear relationship

startDay  = 32

y = np.array([-60,-63,-65,-64,-64,-71,-70,-74,-74,-73,-73,-70,-71,-74,-74,-75,-75,-74,-72,-73,-76,-76,-76,-76,-74,-73,-76,-76,-77,-77,-75,-75,-73,-73,-77,-77,-77,-76,-74,-73,-74,-76,-75,-77,-76,-73,-70,-73,-75,-75,-75,-76,-74,-70,-72,-74,-74,-74,-73,-70,-68,-69,-72,-72,-72,-72,-70,-67,-69,-68,-69,-70,-70,-65,-64,-63,-67,-67,-66,-68,-63,-60,-63,-64,-65,-66,-64,-60,-58,-61,-62,-64,-63,-61,-57,-56,-56,-59,-60])

endDay = startDay + len(y)

x= np.arange(len(y))

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
# for creating pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
# creating pipeline and fitting it on data
Input=[('polynomial',PolynomialFeatures(degree=2))]
pipe=Pipeline(Input)
pipe.fit(x.reshape(-1,1),y.reshape(-1,1))

poly_pred=pipe.predict(x.reshape(-1,1))
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'PolynomialFeatures' object has no attribute 'predict' on line 9
> poly_pred=pipe.predict(x.reshape(-1,1))

I tried searching on google but no good. Can you tell me what is happening, why is the error occurring?

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (since never executed), and it should not be included here. The same holds true for any code that is also irrelevant like plots etc (edited out).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html). `PolynomialFeatures` does not have any method like `predict`. This module is not to predict anything, it is only for data preprocessing.

Comment: That's not exactly accurate, as the module does have a `transform` method, which, practically speaking, works like a `predict` one. A complete answer here would be to use `transform` instead of `predict`.

Comment: @desertnaut i know transform function from standardscalar. Will check this as well in context of PolynomialFeatures.